# Select some elements in a Numpy array according to a specific Boolean condition

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have two lists like this

```
sampled_series = [ 488, 1223, 1958, 2693, 3428]
cum_array = [ 100,  190,  340,  540,  590,  940, 1340, 1410, 1640, 2040, 2940, 3396, 3630, 3675]
```

I want to do following operation.

1. Take first element from `sampled_series` and compare it with all the elements in the `cum_array`.
2. Where the element in the `cum_array` is greater than the sampled_series **for the first time**, return the previous element in the `cum_array` and break the loop
3. Do the same operation again

For example, `540` in `cum_array` is greater than the first element of the `sampled_array`,i.e. `488` in this case print the value `340`, which is the previous element

The code that I have written is this one:

```
for i in range(0, len(sampled_series)):
    for j in range(0, len(cum_array)):
        if sampled_series[i]<cum_array[j]:
            print(cum_array[j-1])
        break
```

When I run the code, there are no errors, but I also see nothing printed. The code just runs smoothly without any error and without any output.

What I expect to see is this

```
340
940
1640
2040
3396
```

PS: I am trying to accomplish **probability proportional to size sampling** through this program.

Here is what it is

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Probability-proportional-to-size_sampling

Comment: Print the values of i and j in each iteration. It will help in knowing if that print line is reached or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fast way to do that in `numpy` with `searchsorted`. I converted your lists to numpy arrays, and then, with searchsorted, find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order:

```
ss = np.array([ 488, 1223, 1958, 2693, 3428])
ca = np.array([ 100,  190,  340,  540,  590,  940, 1340, 1410, 1640, 2040, 2940, 3396, 3630, 3675])
idx=np.searchsorted(ca,ss)
```

Since you want the previous value, substract one:

```
result=ca[idx-1]
#array([ 340,  940, 1640, 2040, 3396])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you `break` out the inner for loop unconditionally. Another problem is that you can get out of range of the cum_array when you condition is true and `j` is zero.

Try this corrected code:

```
sampled_series = [ 488, 1223, 1958, 2693, 3428]
cum_array = [ 100,  190,  340,  540,  590,  940, 1340, 1410, 1640, 2040, 2940, 3396, 3630, 3675]

for i in range(0, len(sampled_series)):
    for j in range(0, len(cum_array)):
        if sampled_series[i]<cum_array[j] and j>0:
            print(cum_array[j-1])
            break
```

EDIT: i forgot to break the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
t=[]
for i in range(0, len(sampled_series)):
    for j in range(0, len(cum_array)):
        if sampled_series[i] < cum_array[j]:
            t.append(cum_array[j-1])
            break
```